# Error when adding a Service Reference for a Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asmx, wcf-client

I am in a .NET programming class and am creating a simple web service and a console tester to work with it. I am using C#, the IBM .Net data provider (have also tried it with the OLE DB data provider) - both data providers can successfully access and retrieve/update data from the server, and the .NET Framework 3.5. 
The web service works, the console tester works (in it's current state), but when I try to add the service reference to link the two together I am getting the following error:

Method not found: '?'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'httppp://localhost:64302/WebServiceV2/Service.asmx'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'httppp://localhost:64302/WebServiceV2/Service.asmx'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

VS 2010 is able to discover the reference, but when I try to expand the webservice.asmx file or if I press OK, I get this error.

I am running VS 2010 Pro SP1 on a Windows 7 machine (64 bit), on a PC that I use for work.
I have tried to "repair" VS 2010 and I have uninstalled/re-installed it but cannot get around this error. As mentioned I have installed SP1. Also I have installed the "CU3" update, which from what I can tell is a "cumulative" update for VS 2010.

I have discussed this error with my class instructor, fellow co-workers, and the CTO of my company. None of these people have experienced this nor can they duplicate this error with VS 2010 and are at a loss to explain it. This leads me to believe that VS 2010 is okay but there might be something else on my PC that is causing this error - or perhaps I might be missing a key update of some sort. My next approach will be to install this on my home PC (Windows 7 as well) to see if I get different results.

Comment: Does the error really say `httppp`? That seems like it should be `http`.

Comment: @Tim: if he's using a Service Reference, then he's using WCF on the client.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Valid point.  Thanks for clarifying.